# Bind9 works properly but I can’t ping names from the DNS server machine

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I have the machine `dnsserver` with the bind9 service in domain `ent.com`. I also boot other machines: `firewall` and `webserver`. All machines are operated by Ubuntu-server-22.04.

I’ve configured these files:

`/etc/bind/named.conf.options`

```bash
listen-on {
        192.168.0.0/24;
}
allow-query { any ;};
dnssec-validation auto;
forwarders {
                192.168.0.1;
        };
```

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```bash
zone "ent.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/forward.ent.com";
        allow-transfer {192.168.0.211; };
        also-notify {192.168.0.211; };
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/reverse.ent.com";
};
```

The zone files.
`/etc/bind/forward.ent.com`

```bash
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dnsserver.ent.com. root.dnsserver.ent.com. (
                            5       ; Serial
                        604800      ; Refresh
                        86400       ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                        604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      dnsserver.ent.com.
@       IN      A       192.168.0.211
dnsserver       IN      A       192.168.0.211
firewall        IN      A       192.168.0.201
mailserver      IN      A       192.168.0.212
webserver       IN      A       192.168.0.213
vault   IN      A       192.168.0.214
```

`/etc/bind/forward.ent.com`

```bash
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dnsserver.ent.com. root.dnsserver.ent.com. (
                            2       ; Serial
                        604800      ; Refresh
                        86400       ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                        604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      dnsserver.ent.com.
@       IN      PTR     ent.com.
211     IN      PTR     dnsserver.ent.com.
201     IN      PTR     firewall.ent.com.
212     IN      PTR     mailserver.ent.com.
213     IN      PTR     webserver.ent.com.
214     IN      PTR     vault.ent.com.
```

Commands `named`, `checkconf` and `checkzone` work without any issues.

So, when I connect to `firewall` and ping machines by their names, it works perfectly:

```bash
ilya@firewall:~$ nslookup dnsserver
Server:      127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    dnsserver.ent.com
Address: 192.168.0.211

ilya@firewall:~$ ping webserver
PING webserver.ent.com (192.168.0.213) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from webserver.ent.com (192.168.0.213): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.567 ms
64 bytes from webserver.ent.com (192.168.0.213): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.657 ms
64 bytes from webserver.ent.com (192.168.0.213): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.514 ms
^C
--- webserver.ent.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2028ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.514/0.579/0.657/0.059 ms
```

But when try to ping names from `dnsserver` I have an error:

```bash
ilya@dnsserver:~$ ping webserver
ping: webserver: Temporary failure in name resolution
ilya@dnsserver:~$ ping firewall
ping: firewall: Temporary failure in name resolution

ilya@dnsserver:~$ nslookup webserver
Server:      127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find webserver: SERVFAIL
```

The `dnsserver`’s netplan configuration is here:

```bash
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens33:
    dhcp4: no
    match:
        macaddress: 00:0c:29:7b:56:ad
    set-name: ext0
    addresses:
        - 192.168.0.211/24
    gateway4: 192.168.0.1
    nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.211]
        search: [ent.com]
```

Can’t find the mistake in my DNS server configuration. Could you help me?

Comment: In your questions please refrain from using random domain names (that you don't own/operate) and use either your *own domain* or one of the [RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761#section-6.5) reserved domain names such as  `example.com`, `example.org`  or similar . Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate.  - Second, is the problem only with resolving "short" hostnames ? Or do you also see a failure when using the FQDN  *webserver.ent.com*  and/or when resolving other domain names?

Comment: Is `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved.service` showing anything helpful?

Comment: @diya, thank you for your crucial remarks! It seems to be solved after the last VMware upgrade. I've started machines that morning and now I can ping long and short names successfully.